# Snowsql: Asynchronous execution of erroneous SQL Stmts, but no error as result

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm currently using Powershell and snowsql to execute numerous SQL statements asynchronously and want snowsql to raise an error on exit, if one of those sql statements couldn't be executed succesfully.

```
echo "insert into doesntexist (select 1);> select 1;>" | snowsql -o sfqid_in_error=true -o log_level=DEBUG -o exit_on_error=true --config "path/to/config"
```

The response I get is:

```
* SnowSQL * v1.2.21
Type SQL statements or !help
Goodbye!
```

But the insert statement doesn't run successfully. I would assume snowsql to exit with an error (hence exit_on_error=true) but this isn't the case.

Is this on purpose or a bug or has someone a better idea to solve this?

KR

Comment: I believe you need to check and handle the exit in the script (powershell in your case). For powershell you might need something like $LASTEXITCODE to check and take action if its non-zero, for unix it would be something like $?. Also there is another similar post that you can check here - https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z000074XAFKSA4/snowsql-exit-code

Comment: Yeah, that’s what I do. The lastexitcode is 0

Comment: I don't believe can "pipe in" the SQL statement statement into the SnowSQL command in the way you are trying to - you would need to construct the complete SnowSQL command and then execute it.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm currently using Powershell and snowsql to execute numerous SQL
> statements asynchronously

As you execute the SQLs asynchronously, the results are not checked by SnowSQL. This is why it doesn't return any error. If you want to monitor if the queries were successfully executed, you can:

1. wait until all queries are completed, and check the results. This
   can be done by using the query_history functions but it will require
   some coding (maybe you can use Snowflake Scripting for this).
2. execute the queries synchronously.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but solution 1 crossed my mind as well. A missing feature of snowsql in my eyes.